# Sharepoint Modal Dialog with no Title

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

I have a requirement where i dont want to display "Title" in the Modal Dialog. If i pass an empty string to the title, the modal dialog displays the title as "Dialog" .I dont want anything to display as the Title.

Any idea on how it can be acieved?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[image]

Put empty white space in `title`. Example:

```
var options =
    {
    title: ' ',        
        url: '/_layouts/15/NY.ExportVersionHistory/ExportVersionHistory.aspx',
        height: 400,
        width: 300
    }

    SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog(options);
```

**UPDATE**

Having empty space in title should not result in any title being displayed in popup. Check the screenshot.

Comment: An empty space displays the title as "Dialog" in the modal dialog.Gave a try on it..dint work

Comment: That's weird. it should work. Worked for me in the past

Comment: You can mark it as an answer if you feel if it helped resolve your issue.

Answer (score 1):

One way to achieve this is by hiding the Title bar using CSS

```
<style type="text/css">
body div.ms-dlgBorder div.ms-dlgTitle
{
    display:none;
}   
</style>
```

Comment: This will hide the title for any of the modal popup which come up in a page, rather i would want to hide it only to a specific popup.

Comment: You can dynamically add/remove this Style based on the popup. For ex: if the dialog is opened on button click, handle that click event and add the style. Then remove it on the dialog exit handler.

Comment: May i know whether the code has to be written in the page coming up in the modal dialog or in the page where the modal dialog is present?

Comment: Page where you are invoking the dialog.